# Java copy and rename image file into another directory

Tags: java, file

```
   String name = "";
   File destFile = new File(folderPath + catalogueFileName + itemName.getText());
   if (!destFile.exists()) {
       destFile.createNewFile();
   }

   FileChannel fileSource = new FileInputStream(imagePath).getChannel();
   FileChannel destination = new FileInputStream(folderPath
       + catalogueFileName ).getChannel();
   destination.transferFrom(fileSource, 0, fileSource.size());

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A new entry added successfully.");
   if (fileSource != null) {
       fileSource.close();
   }
   if (destination != null) {
       destination.close();
   }
```

I am using the code above to copy image file and rename the image file into another directory if user input itemname = "music", I want the image name rename to music. the image extension

But I got this exception

```
Exception occurred during event dispatching:
java.nio.channels.NonWritableChannelException
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferFrom(FileChannelImpl.java:584)
```

Answer (score 2):

`destination` should probably be a `FileOutputStream`, right?

```
FileChannel destination = new FileOutputStream(folderPath
       + catalogueFileName).getChannel();
```

If you just want to copy or move a file, you should use [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/). There is a [moveFile](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29) method and a [copyFile](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29) method.

Comment: Is it possible to rename the image file to user input item name said for source the name is ABC.jpg then if user input is music then when copy the image file to destination rename it to music.jpg.

Comment: To move a file from one filename to another, I'd use [Apache Commons Fileutil's](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) [moveFile](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveFile(java.io.File,%20java.io.File)) method.

Comment: Can don't use third party is it possible?

Comment: Yes, but I'll leave homework as an [exercise](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html) for the student.